# Definite Integral of Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> I'm looking to find someone to either verify or correct my computation of the definite integral $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)~dx$$
>   where $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+n)^{n}}$$

What I came up with seems too complicated -- I just don't trust the result.  But here's what I have:

Using the fact that the sum of the integral is the integral of the sum for series of functions that are uniformly convergent on $[0, \infty)$ (established previously), I computed $$\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x)~dx$$ for each $n = 1, 2, 3 \ldots$:

for $n = 1$ $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+1)} dx = \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{u} du = \left. \text{log}(u) \right|_1^2 = \text{log}(2) - \text{log}(1) = \text{log}(2)$$

for $n = 2$ $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+2)^{2}} dx = \int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{u^{2}} du = \left. -\frac{1}{u}\right|_2^3 = -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$$

for $n = 3$ $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+3)^{3}} dx = \int_{3}^{4} \frac{1}{u^{3}} du = \left. -\frac{1}{2u^{2}}\right|_3^4 = -\frac{1}{2\cdot4^{2}} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^{2}} = \frac{7}{288}$$

for $n = 4$ $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+4)^{4}} dx = \int_{4}^{5} \frac{1}{u^{4}} du = \left. -\frac{1}{3u^{3}}\right|_4^5 = -\frac{1}{3\cdot5^{3}} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4^{3}} = \frac{61}{24000}$$

or the general formula 
$$log(2) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+2)^{n} - (n+1)^{n}}{n\cdot(n + 2)^{n} \cdot (n+1)^{n}} \approx .886882$$

Is this correct, or did I mess up somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very correct. You could have made your life easier compute the antiderivative using (as you did) $u=x+n$ and come back to $x$ directly and get the integral.